# Visual C++ ATL Com registration issue

Tags: regsvr32

I have a Visual C++ 6 project that is creating a COM DLL.  This is an old project that I have not used in years but I came back to it recently to update some functionality of the DLL.  The issue I am having is that when I try to manually register the DLL (using regsvr32) that is created by the project, I get no response whatsoever.  It does not say it succeeds and it does not say it fails.  I have verified that the DLL is not being added to the registry.  I have never seen a situation with regsvr32 when it would not show any confirmation message.

Also, the DLL is set to self-register in the project and when it attempts to do this, it also does not show a message.

I have not touched this project in a long time, but the last time I did touch it, it worked without issue.  Now I come back to it, and all of the sudden I am having this problem. It is as if the DLL being created by the Visual C++ project is not compatible with the current version of Windows.  I have updated the development software to SP6 but it has not changed the situation.

I ran Depends on regsvr32 when it was pointing to the created DLL, and it shows this message:

LoadLibraryExW("C:\Source32\BIS\Projects\ALFA\DigiPixSvc\DigiPixObj\Debug\DigiPixObj", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The operating system cannot run %1 (182).

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and what I can do to correct it?

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you trying to run regsvr32 as an administrator?

Comment: OS is Windows XP SP3.  I am logged in as an administrator when I run regsvr32.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in `DLLRegisterServer()` and then debug what happens when you run regsvr32?

Comment: I've never done that before. How would I get it to stop at the breakpoint inside of the Visual C++ IDE during the regsvr32 operation?

Comment: See the answer that I added about debugging your DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: since I don't have VS 6.0 installed anymore, I'll have to use some Google searches to give you the exact steps for the VC 6.0 dialogs - so some of this information may be inaccurate. I believe it's correct - it's really what you'd do in the current IDE, just for VC 6.0.

Before you go through the trouble of debugging your DLL, make sure you run it through [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to verify that all your dependencies are on your machine. Don't run *Dependency Walker* on regsvr32 - what matters is whether your DLL has its dependencies. If they're missing, regsvr32 won't be able to load the DLL.

To see if your DLL is getting loaded by regsvr32 when you try to register it, you need to debug through the `DLLRegisterServer()` function and see what happens there - this is one of the 4 entry points a COM DLL must have and regsvr32 calls this function when the DLL is about to be registered. In order to do this, you'll have to set regsvr32 as the startup program of your project and pass the full path to your debug-built DLL as a command-line parameter to regsvr32.

- Bring up *Project Properties* for your project.
- Go to the *Debug* tab.
- Make sure the *General* category is selected.
- Enter the full path to regsvr32 in the *Executable for debug session* textbox.
- Enter the full path to the debug version of your DLL in the *Program arguments* textbox. Make sure you have a PDB file for your DLL so you can see symbol information during debugging.
- Put a breakpoint on the first line in `DLLRegisterServer()`. The code in this function may be long or short, depending on how it was created: generated by a wizard, written by a developer, etc.
- Start debugging.

Your breakpoint should be hit and you should be able to step through the registration code and see at which point it fails.

Comment: I found the problem, which was that there was a dependency DLL tied to a static library being used by my DLL.  The static library had been updated properly but the old version of the dependency DLL was sitting in the build directory and had not been updated to match the updated static library.  When I used the latest dependency DLL, then regsvr32 said that it properly registered my DLL.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help.  What you said in your answer ultimately led to me tracking down the issue.